# Why is sed returning more characters than requested

Tags: sed

In a part of my script I am trying to generate a list of the year and month that a file was submitted. Since the file contains the timestamp, I should be able to cut the filenames to the month position, and then do a sort+uniq filtering. However sed is generating an outlier for one of the files.

I am using this command sequence

```
  ls -1 service*json | sed -e "s|\(.*201...\).*json$|\1|g" | sort |uniq
```

And this works for most of time except in some cases it outputs the whole timestamp:

```
$ ls
service-parent-20181119092630.json  service-parent-20181123134132.json  service-parent-20181202124532.json  service-parent-20190121091830.json  service-parent-20190125124209.json
service-parent-20181119101003.json  service-parent-20181126104300.json  service-parent-20181211095939.json  service-parent-20190121092453.json  service-parent-20190128163539.json
service-parent-20181120095850.json  service-parent-20181127083441.json  service-parent-20190107035508.json  service-parent-20190122093608.json
service-parent-20181120104838.json  service-parent-20181129155835.json  service-parent-20190107042234.json  service-parent-20190122115053.json

$ ls -1 service*json | sed -e "s|\(.*201...\).*json$|\1|g" | sort |uniq
service-parent-201811
service-parent-201811201048
service-parent-201812
service-parent-201901
```

I have also tried this variation but the second output line is still returned:

```
  ls -1 service*json | sed -e "s|\(.*201.\{3\}\).*json$|\1|g" | sort |uniq
```

Can somebody explain why service-parent-201811201048 is returned past the requested 3 characters?

Thanks.

Comment: When you say `the file contains the timestamp` - do you really mean that the file **name** contains the timestamp? It looks that way from your example, just making sure....

Comment: Yes they do. The files are regular extracts from a source system and fed to time-series database. The database however is not accessible to me  (its in a VPN) but I have access to the extract files up to a certain date.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`service-parent-201811201048` happens to have `201048` to match `201...`.

Might try `ls -1 service*json | sed -e "s|\(.*-201...\).*json$|\1|g" | sort |uniq` to ask for a dash `-` before `201...`.

Comment: Selecting this as the proper answer because it explains why I am getting weird results. Thanks for pointing it out as my eyes are more weary than I thought. :)

Answer (score 0):

It is not recommended to parse the output of `ls`. Please try instead:

```
for i in service*json; do
    sed -e "s|^\(service-.*-201[0-9]\{3\}\).*json$|\1|g" <<< "$i"
done | sort | uniq
```

Comment: Noted. The sample syntax is meant to simplify the scenario that I can recreate. I am already using a loop to filter the files.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is explained at https://stackoverflow.com/a/54565973/1745001 (i.e. `.*` is greedy) but try this:

```
$ ls | sed -E 's/(-[0-9]{6}).*/\1/' | sort -u
service-parent-201811
service-parent-201812
service-parent-201901
```

The above requires a sed that supports EREs via `-E`, e.g. GNU sed and OSX/BSD sed.

Comment: Thanks, this also works but I have to select @packard-cpw's answer as it explains the reason for the weird output. Being greedy is a bit more high-level to regexp newbies like me. :)